# Datatable moment plugin not working as expected

Tags: jquery, datatables, momentjs

So, I have a datatables page where I need to sort by date which is in the following format: HH:mm:ss DD/MM/YYYY.

I am using the Datatables moment js plugin. I have tried this one: https://datatables.net/blog/2014-12-18#Completed-plug-in 
, as well as this one: https://datatables.net/plug-ins/sorting/datetime-moment

thing is, the plugin seems to exclusively pay attention to the HH:mm:ss part, disregarding the date part, even seeming to sort that backwards.

One of the last experiments I have done is running this slightly modified version and taking notes:

```
$.fn.dataTable.moment = function ( format, locale ) {
    console.log('moment function.');

    var types = $.fn.dataTable.ext.type;

    // Add type detection
    types.detect.unshift(function (d) {
        if (d) {
            // Strip HTML tags and newline characters if possible
            if ( d.replace ) {
                d = d.replace(/(<.*?>)|(\r?\n|\r)/g, '');
            }

            // Strip out surrounding white space
            d = $.trim( d );
        }

        // Null and empty values are acceptable
        if (d === '' || d === null) {
            return 'moment-' + format;
        }

        return moment(d, format, locale, true).isValid() ?
            'moment-' + format :
            null;
    } );

    // Add sorting method - use an integer for the sorting
    types.order['moment-' + format + '-pre'] = function (d) {
        if (d) {
            // Strip HTML tags and newline characters if possible
            if ( d.replace ) {
                d = d.replace(/(<.*?>)|(\r?\n|\r)/g, '');
            }

            // Strip out surrounding white space
            d = $.trim( d );
        }

        console.log('unformatted: ' + d);
        console.log('moment:');
        console.log(moment(d, format, locale, true));
        console.log('format x: ' + parseInt(moment(d, format, locale, true).format('x'), 10));

        return !moment(d, format, locale, true).isValid() ?
            Infinity :
            parseInt(moment(d, format, locale, true).format('x'), 10);
    };
};
```

With results such as:

```
unformatted: 19:13:28 16/07/2019 login_attempts:63:21
moment: login_attempts:64:21
Object { _isAMomentObject: true, _i: "19:13:28 16/07/2019", _f: "HH:mm:ss DD/MM/YYYY", _strict: true, _isUTC: false, _pf: {…}, _locale: {…}, _d: Date Tue Jul 16 2019 19:13:28 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time), _isValid: true }
login_attempts:65:21
format x: 1563297208000 login_attempts:66:21
unformatted: 19:13:27 16/07/2019 login_attempts:63:21
moment: login_attempts:64:21
Object { _isAMomentObject: true, _i: "19:13:27 16/07/2019", _f: "HH:mm:ss DD/MM/YYYY", _strict: true, _isUTC: false, _pf: {…}, _locale: {…}, _d: Date Tue Jul 16 2019 19:13:27 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time), _isValid: true }
login_attempts:65:21
format x: 1563297207000 login_attempts:66:21
unformatted: 19:13:26 16/07/2019 login_attempts:63:21
moment: login_attempts:64:21
Object { _isAMomentObject: true, _i: "19:13:26 16/07/2019", _f: "HH:mm:ss DD/MM/YYYY", _strict: true, _isUTC: false, _pf: {…}, _locale: {…}, _d: Date Tue Jul 16 2019 19:13:26 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time), _isValid: true }
login_attempts:65:21
format x: 1563297206000
```

As you can see, perfectly valid results. The gotcha, though, is these are printed only before I re-sort. Meaning, in essence, that when I see these, those datetimes are now in the last page for me (thought that was worth mentioning, it seems odd to me.)

I have also tried this:

```
 columnDefs: [{
      targets: [8], //index of column
      type: 'date'
    }]
```

and the same but with 'datetime-moment', because I read it somewhere. Made no difference.

The software used besides this sorting plugin is:

- laravel 5.2
- Yajra Datatables plugin v6.29.0
- Datatables 1.10.16
- moment js 2.24.0

The data is provided via ajax. Could that be an issue?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Can you maybe add your example as a code snippet or in a fiddle? You can make a mock json with your data as well using https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/ or https://www.mocky.io/. Someone would be able to give a better answer or response to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found out what's going on.

It seems it IS the Yajra datatables plugin that actually is doing the sorting.

Thing is: In my login attempts model, I have this server side date formatting method:

```
public function getAttemptedAtAttribute($value) {
    return toDMY2($value);
}
```

toDMY2 being a function that returns the european formatted date using the Carbon library.

Problem is, the Yajra datatables plugin seems to be unable to recognize that as a date.

Therefore, my solution is as follows: I have removed the server side formatting entirely, relying instead on moment js to format the column, as follows:

```
"columns": [

      [...]

      { "data": "attempted_at", "render": function(data, type, row) {
        return moment(data).format('HH:mm:ss DD/MM/YYYY');
      }, "orderable": true},
],
```